# Rust reset Arc<Mutex<T>> to a new T instance?

Tags: rust

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait B{}

struct A{
}

impl B for A{}


fn main() {
    let a = A{};
    let b: Arc<Mutex<dyn B>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(a));
    //Can I lock `b` and change the inner `a`?
    
}
```

I wanted something like this:

```
    b.lock().unwrap().reset(A{});
```

I though of doing

```
let b: Arc<Mutex<Option<dyn B>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(a));

error[E0277]: the size for values of type `dyn B` cannot be known at compilation time
   --> src/main.rs:13:12
    |
13  |     let b: Arc<Mutex<Option<dyn B>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Some(a)));
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `Sized` is not implemented for `dyn B`

but it won't work, it says `B` is not `Sized`.
```

Why there's no easy way to do this?

I could explain why I want this but I think the question would be too long. But basically I want to be able to call an `Arc<Mutex<dyn B>>` even if its inner object gets changed.

Comment: The provided code compiles just fine. Please providea MCVE that reproduces the problem.

Comment: `*b.get_mut().unwrap() = A{};` as shown in [the docs for `get_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#method.get_mut).

Comment: @Jmb I don't think you can call `Mutex::get_mut()` because the mutex is behind an `Arc`, and `Mutex::get_mut()` takes `&mut self`. Normally this would be resolved by using something like `*b.lock().unwrap() = ...`, but it's unclear what to put instead of `...` for it to compile. The OP is storing a trait object in the `Arc<Mutex<...>>` which works because the value is behind a pointer, but makes it hard to produce a new such value. There is also `Arc::get_mut()`, but it requires the refcount to be 1, which is probably not what the OP needs, and it probably runs into the same issue with `dyn`.

Comment: The obvious solution would be to store a `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn B>>>` if you are willing to do the small extra allocation.

Comment: Just to state the obvious here, your trait object does not have a known size at compile time, so you can't replace it with a different trait object, which might have a different size, so it can't just be placed in the same allocation.

Comment: @SvenMarnach I think your comment should be the answer - what the OP is trying to do is fundamentally incompatible with `Arc`. Although `Arc` does allow putting a trait object behind it, it allocates only once and points to that allocation. Replacing a trait object with a different trait object would require resizing the allocation in-place (which is not possible) or always using an extra indirection and allocation, which result in all `Arc`s paying the cost of this use case. The solution is to use `Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn B>>>` and replace it with `*b.lock().unwrap() = Box::new(A {})`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a concrete type `T` it's perfectly possible to reset `Arc<Mutex<T>>` to a new `T` instance, just use `*x.lock().unwrap() = new_t`, or even `old_t = mem::replace(x.lock().unwrap(), new_t)`. But what you're attempting is something different, and that's replacing an *unsized trait object* with another one.

What you're trying to do is not allowed because an `Arc` represents shared ownership of a single concrete allocation. In other words, `Arc::new(Mutex::new(A {}))` allocates a block large enough to hold enough Arc's control information (the reference count) and a `Mutex<A>`. You can view that pointer as `Arc<Mutex<dyn B>>`, but that doesn't give you ability to place the value of a different type into the allocation. This is not allowed for two reasons:

- the other type could be of a different size, and an allocation cannot be resized in-place;
- even if the other type is of the same size, consider that each `Arc<Mutex<dyn B>>` carries a vtable pointer that encodes the implementation of `B` for `A`. If you were to replace `A` with another type that implements `B`, all the clones of the original `Arc<Mutex<dyn B>>` would suddenly become invalid because their vtable pointer is valid for `A`.

To fix both issues, you need to place the indirection inside the mutex:

```
let a = A {};
let b: Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn B>>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Box::new(a)));
// lock `b` and change the inner `a`:
*b.lock().unwrap() = Box::new(A {});
```